# Height of an image does not be affected when having a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am new to html, css. I am doing a basic website with a navigation bar, which always stays on top followed by an image which takes up half the view.

However, when I set the height of body to 100%, and the height of the image is 50%, the height of the image doesn't be affected.

I tried the below code without the navigation bar, and it worked.

Can anyone tell me where the problem comes from?

```css
body, html
{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
/*    background: url("images/aboutmebg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;*/
}

nav
{   
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1;  /*Stay on top*/ 
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li a {
 display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#aboutme img
{   
    
    height: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: "ubuntu";
    src: url("fonts/Ubuntu-Title.ttf");
}
```

```html
 <!-- start "wrap" tag: contains all other tags -->
 <div id="wrap">
  <!-- start "nav" tag -->
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#aboutme">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">experiences</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">skills</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- end "nav" tag -->

  <!-- start "home" tag: contains bg img and information -->
  <div id="aboutme">
   <img id="aboutmebg" src="images/aboutmebg.jpg" alt="Could not load this image">
  </div>
  <!-- end "home" tag -->

 <!-- end "wrap" tag -->
 </div>
```

[image: result of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

The parent containers of the image also need height: 100% on them. So give #wrap and #aboutme a height of 100% and it should work.

Comment: and can you explain me why the image automatically has a left margin? (like it is shown in the picture)

Comment: Sure. Image elements are inline style elements so they go to the left. If you want to center the image there are many ways to do that. Two quick ways to do it is to put text-align: center; on the image parent container or make the image display: block; and margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I mean the small space between the edge of webpage and the left side of the image when I say “margin-left” :D why do they appear?

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually not seeing the small space. I've recreated this issue in a Codepen pen with my own image since I don't have access to your image, and I'm not seeing a small space to the left side of the image. https://codepen.io/pavger/pen/ae77f958f451fd759ef37fa8a52983f8/

Comment: it’s weird :)) I have captured my result above, can you have a look?

Comment: Just to make sure, does your image have a white border around it as part of the image itself? Otherwise I'm not sure why it's not aligned perfectly to the left side. I can only take a look at your screenshot since your code snippet doesn't have the image in it.

Comment: no, it doesn’t. I tend to set the src attribute of the image to the website, where stores it. but I can remember the correct link :D But thanks a lot. I’ll check it later